# Dynamic Sales Summary Depending on Month (can't use MAXIF/MINIF)

Tags: excel, datatable, worksheet-function, excel-2016

I have a student license of Office Pro 2016, but somehow it doesn't have the IFS, MINIF/MINIFS, MAXIF/MAXIFS functions that would make my life so much easier. I tried to illustrate what I'm doing in the image below:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbLnY.png)

My actual data is much more complicated and long, but the idea is that I will periodically manually update data within the DATATABLE, and I want the SUMMARYTABLE to reflect the total pending sales by month. There are never more than two months pending at a time, and if only sales from one particular month are pending, I don't want the second row to appear.

I've already found a way to display the month in this case using regular MAX and MIN functions, but now I'm stumped as to how to display the sum total of sales within those months. Specifically, I don't know how to make a reference to a particular month in my criteria.

I've tried this formula:
=SUMIFS(DATATABLE[SALES],DATATABLE[SHOP]="A",DATATABLE[STATUS]="PENDING",*MONTH(DATATABLE[DATE])*,SHOPATOTALS[MONTH])

If this worked it would have been perfect, but the month portion isn't recognized as a proper range.

Comment: You will need to use an Array version of SUM(IF()) like you have done with MAX(IF()) and MIN(IF()).

Comment: @Scott Craner Thanks! It turns out I was simply unfamiliar with how to write multiple condition array formulas, but in the end I figured it out!

Something like this:

`{=SUM(IF((MONTH(DATATABLE[DATE])=SHOPATOTALS[MONTH])*(DATATABLE[SHOP]="A")*(DATATABLE[STATUS]="PENDING"),DATATABLE[SALES],0)}`